# Unity Fungus Flowchart doesn't receive message with my script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my Player to interact with object, so I use Fungus and a script that when the Player is close enough to the object and I press E, it sends a message to Flowchart to activate a block. But it doesn't work.

The script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EventTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool enter;

    int count = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        enter = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" || other.gameObject.tag == "NPC")
        {
            enter = true;
            if (enter && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                Fungus.Flowchart.BroadcastFungusMessage("StartConversation");
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" || other.gameObject.tag == "NPC")
        {
            enter = false;
            count = 1;
        }
        Debug.Log("Exited");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Fungus, but have you checked if your collider's trigger events are being invoked? Keep in mind you have to check "IsTrigger" in the collider properties for these methods to be invoked.

Comment: are you sure that section of code is running?

Comment: @MatheusRocha I put the debug.log upon enter to see if they work, put it doesn't appear in the log. Yeah the NPC has his IsTrigger checked. :/

Comment: @BornaUngar As soon as I get home I'll test some things. It's most likely a collider configuration issue. I've had problems with that, it's usually no big deal.

Answer (score 2):

`OnTriggerEnter` is called once, and you are listening to input only during one frame.
Consider moving this part to Update:

```
if (enter && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
{
    Fungus.Flowchart.BroadcastFungusMessage("StartConversation");
}
```

or changing `OnTriggerEnter` to `OnTriggerStay`

Comment: Well noted, however the asker is having problems getting the trigger events to be called.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Fungus, however, as mentioned in the comments, you're having trouble getting the event to be called upon Collision.

Please take the following into account:

1. Colliders must be marked `IsTrigger` for `OnTriggerXXX` to be called, however, trigger colliders are non-physical, this means if you only have 1 trigger collider in your gameobject, other physical objects can pass through them. To fix this, you can either add a second collider with `IsTrigger` unchecked, OR, you can uncheck `IsTrigger` and use `OnCollisionXXX` instead. **I'd suggest the latter solution.**
2. Make sure your colliders can actually collide.

   1. Go to "Edit > Project Settings > Physics", scroll down until you see "Layer Collision Matrix" and make sure the checkbox in the intersection of your objects' layers is checked.
   2. Make sure the two colliders can actually collide during play. This is common with character collisions. You might have a simple box or cylider physical collider around your characters, but have an inner mesh collider be the trigger on your NPC. This way your player character can never collide with the trigger inside the physical collider.
3. This may sound stupid, but make sure you added your script to correct object. I've lost the count of how many times I went through an unecessary frustration after writting a script and forgetting to add it to the test object.

This should be enough to ensure your events are actually called.
Now, please note that, as pointed out by Hermesis, you're trying to read input in a 1-frame event. You're also using `Input.GetKeyDown()` which is also a 1-frame check, that is, it will only return true on the frame when the key state has changed.

In your code, the condition `(enter && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))` will only ever be true, if the user happens to press the key in the exact frame the collision begins.

Again, as noted by Hermesis, consider using "OnXXXStay" instead of "OnXXXEnter".

Here are some tips:

- Use `OnXXXEnter` to display a message to the player so he knows he is in contact with an interactable, and also knows which key(s) can do what.
- Use `OnXXXStay` to respond to keypresses only while the collision is happening.
- Use `OnXXXExit` to clear the message that was set upon collision.

I hope this helps.